# Assembly for malware analysis

Tags: assembly

I know we have some architectures for assembly language. But I wanna know this: I need learn x86 assembly ? , or arm assembly ? , or both ? , or others ?..

Please help me , what should I learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the short term, you'll likely need to understand and debug both x86 and ARM assembly, even if you don't write in them. Here's why:

- Analyzing malware demands the skill to read and track its behavior.
- A significant portion of malware targets Windows and Linux on x86 systems, which underscores the importance of x86 assembly knowledge.
- Based on data from [av-atlas](https://portal.av-atlas.org/malware) and other sources, the next major targets are Android and MacOS, emphasizing the need for ARM assembly knowledge.
- The importance of ARM assembly in this area is growing as the number of devices with ARM processors increases, presenting more potential targets for malware.

By learning x86 assembly, you address most of your assembly language related malware analysis requirements, with ARM assembly serving as a beneficial, and at times necessary, addition.